# Swagger: how to define header in swagger file

Tags: api, swagger, swagger-2.0

I am confused with swagger header definition.
in the official document, it says that

*`Note: Header parameters named Accept, Content-Type and Authorization are not allowed. To describe these headers, use the corresponding OpenAPI keywords:`*

https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/#header-parameters

My header is below. Only contains `"Content-type", "Accept", "Authorization"` . Does that means I dont have to define the header in swagger under parameter since my header doesn't contain an unique custom value ?

```
content_headers_func_a = {
    "Content-type":"application/json",
    "Accept":"application/json",
    "Authorization" : "password"
    }
```

Comment: Yes, that's what the doc means. Note that the doc is for OpenAPI 3.0 (`openapi: 3.0.0`); if you use OpenAPI 2.0 (`swagger: '2.0'`) refer to this doc instead: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/describing-parameters/#header-parameters

Comment: Thank you for answering the question !